# Change checkbox to change in db in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, checkbox

I have a table "User" with "admin" is "true" or "false". I show it with checkbox_feild. How can i change db if i clicked in checkbox? Thanks all.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= form_for user, do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :admin%>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: why you dont want to use ajax..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to write a jquery script that submits the form when checkbox is clicked

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= form_for user,:html => {class: 'form'} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.check_box :admin%>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Jquery script would be:

```
$('.form input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){
    $(".form").submit();
});
```

Comment: I did so but it does not work bro. I add alert to this jQuery to test but it still does not work.

Comment: Thanks. I edited it to
$('.field').children().change(function(){
    $(".form").submit();
 });
Tks very much.

Comment: Kindly upvote and accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks!